# Unit test for httpserverletrequest from Java object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dropwizard

I have written the unit test which was passing without any issues:

```
private Example ex;
@BeforeEach
    void setUp(){
        ex = new ex();
    }
@Test
    void funcTest(){
        UserDataType p1 = new UserDataType("");
        Response noResponse = ex.func(p1);
        assertNotNull(noResponse);
        assertEquals(noResponse.getStatus(),Status.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode());
    }


public Response func(@Valid Object Obj) {
        UserDataType p1;
        ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        try {
            String eventJson =  MAPPER.writeValueAsString(obj);
            p1 = MAPPER.readValue(eventJson, UserDataType.class);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                  return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();            
            }

        if (!p1.object.equalsIgnoreCase("something")) {
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build(); // p1 in test has object as ""
        }
```

Now the question is:

Since, I am going to change the `func` in the codebase as follows:

```
public Response func(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
      // do Same thing as above
}
```

Is it possible to wrap the object as HTTPServerLetRequest so that test cases can pass?

1. I am using the `dropwizard` framework.
2. I know in order to get the JSON, I need to use `req.getInputStream()`. I am basically asking on how/what to pass as `req`

Answer (score -1):

The usual way is to use some framework for mock-object (e.g. [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/)), to "mock" HttpServletRequest interface in your unit-test.

Comment: yes, but how to add the Obj in `httpserverletrequest`?

Comment: I have a fealing, that you not really understand how to work with mocks. You have to learn it.

Let's say, your "func" method is using HttpServeltRequest -> getMethod() inside.
In you unit-test you are doing somethign like that:

HttpServeltRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServeltRequest.class);
Mockito.when(request.getMethod()).thenReturn("GET");
Response noResponse = ex.func(request);